# Move to next colum if condition is true when create table with loop in Php

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

so, what i wanted to do is show the total clicks per Category id of the items only for 20 items order by the highest total clicks per day.

now i am using hard code and the result have to looks like this

[image: i am using hard code to t]

so, if the item id and total clicks already fill up the

> 20columns (for item id and total clicks) + 2 for the tittle so means
>   22columns

it has to move to next row.

because i am reffering to my db, so i am using loop to create the table, and when i doing that way, i am getting this result....
[image]

> the result will keep showing until the end in the left side. thats very hard to read for report purposes. so i wanted the result looks like the first figure that i've uploaded.

here is what i am doing now

```
  include "Con.php";
        //get the value from Get Method 
        $CatidValue = $_GET['CatIds'];
        //(The date format would looks like yyyy-mm-dd)
        $DateFrom = $_GET['DateFrom'];  
        $DateTo = $_GET['DateTo'];
        //select the CatID
        $SqlGet= "Select CatId from try where CatId = $CatidValue";
        $_SqlGet = mysqli_query($connection,$SqlGet);
        $TakeResultGet = mysqli_fetch_array($_SqlGet);
        $CatIdTittle = $TakeResultGet ['CatId'];

        echo"
            For Category Id : $CatIdTittle
            <br>

        ";

        //For Loop purpose and break the value
        $explodeValueFrom = explode("-",$DateFrom);
        $explodeValueTo = explode("-",$DateTo);
        $DateValueFrom = $explodeValueFrom[0].$explodeValueFrom[1].$explodeValueFrom[2];
        $DateValueTo = $explodeValueTo[0].$explodeValueTo[1].$explodeValueTo[2];    

        //Loop through the date
        for($Loop=$DateValueFrom; $Loop <= $DateValueTo; $Loop++){
            $YearLoop= substr($Loop, 0,4);
            $MonthLoop =substr($Loop, 4,2);
            $DayLoop = substr($Loop, 6,2);

            $DateTittleValue = $YearLoop."-".$MonthLoop."-".$DayLoop;
            $trValue = "<th class='tg-amwm' colspan='2'>$DateTittleValue</th>";


                echo"
                <table class='tg'>
                    <tr>
                        $trValue
                    </tr>
                ";
                echo"
                <table class='tg'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>Items Id</td>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>Total Clicks</td>
                    </tr>
                ";



            //to get the item id and total clicks
            $SqlSelect = "select `Item Id`,`Total Clicks`,Day from try where CatId = $CatidValue and Day = '$DateTittleValue' ORDER BY `try`.`Total Clicks`  DESC limit 20";
            $_SqlSelect = mysqli_query($connection,$SqlSelect);
            foreach ($_SqlSelect as $ResultSelect) {
                $Day = $ResultSelect['Day'];
                $ItemId = $ResultSelect['Item Id'];
                $TotalClicks = $ResultSelect['Total Clicks'];

                echo"       
                    <tr>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>$ItemId</td>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>$TotalClicks</td>
                    </tr>               
                ";
            }
        }           
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to post a bit more code related to where the data is coming from and if it is database related.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry for that, i've just updated my question and also with the code and also the expecting result

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to declare your trValueTitle in the loop. Plus you need to concatenate it in your echo, try this :

```
    $trValueTittle ="1"."<th class='tg-amwm' colspan='2'>$DateTittleValue</th>" ; 
    echo"<table class='tg'>";
    for($loopForTr=1; $loopForTr<=3; $loopForTr++){
        echo"<tr>". $trValueTittle ."</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: i've just update my question, you question is right, i have already done with this. but i wanted  same as the pict in my question. refer to that

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you want to do with the "1", but I think this is what you want to do:

```
echo "<table class='tg'>";
for($loopForTr=1; $loopForTr<=3; $loopForTr++){
    $trValueTittle ="<th class='tg-amwm' colspan='2'>$DateTittleValue</th>";
    echo"   
        <tr>
            $trValueTittle 
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$trValueTittle ="1"."<th class='tg-amwm' colspan='2'>$DateTittleValue</th>" ;

echo"<table class='tg'>
       <thead>
          <tr>";

for($loopForTr=1; $loopForTr<=3; $loopForTr++){
    echo $trValueTittle;
}

     echo"</tr>
  </thead>
</table>";
```

@Mantello, good answer, but i think it's better to keep out the "tr" from the loop, cause usually you don't want to place your tableheads (th) in different rows.

Comment: my output is iam expecting this 

2009-04-21                        2009-04-22
Item Id Total Clicks Item Id Total Clicks
121321 23                   12224       12
1233 1                   12312        6

your code will generate this
2009-04-21                       
Item Id Total Clicks 
121321 23                   
1233 1
 
2009-04-22  
Item Id Total Clicks    
12224       12             
12312        6

Comment: Sorry i really don't understand what you want.... I've seen the images you posted aboth. As i said, don't place your tr in the for loop... And if you haven't done it, please post more of your code, otherwise i can't help you. :(

Answer (score -2):

@Rax your Code won't work. You'll recive an error. You can't output a Variable the way you did in your echo.

```
echo"<tr> '.$trValueTittle.' </tr>";
```

would be fine. But there's also no need to define your variable inside the for loop. This way you slow up your script.

Comment: Rax's echo is fine. The variable is inside double quotes.

Comment: Oh your right, my bad. Don't know what i've studied while writing this answer.

Comment: That comment about it being wrong should be removed from your answer.